# Axios is repeating prefix route in Laravel

Tags: laravel, axios

I don't know why when I try to make a petition, axios didn't get the route well.

**The error:**
Then here's the **error**, I have a `operations.js` where I make an axios post to the route `operation_calls` as you see below, but I don't know why axios isn't getting only the url I wrote, it is getting repeating twice.

```
const operacionLlamadasApp = new Vue({
    el: '.crud-operation-calls',
    methods:{
        storeOperations(){
            // as you see I only write it once and I expect to go there
            axios.post('operation_calls', {
                  param1 : param1,
                  param2 : param1
            })
            .then(response =>{

            })
        }
    }
});
```

When in the browser I'm in this url, creating a new row: `http://my-domain/operation_calls/create` and click on the save button I expect to go to `operation_calls` store route but I get this error:

```
Request URL: http://my-domain/operation_calls/operation_calls
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
```

As you see, the prefix is repeated when I only typed it once.

Also I have this error in the `response` apart of my browser console:

```
The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT
```

I'm using:

```
Laravel 6.*
Axios: ^0.19
```

I've created routes like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'operation_calls'], function(){
    Route::put('/{id}','OperationsCallController@update');
    Route::resource('/','OperationsCallController', ['names' => [
        'create' => 'operations.create']
    ]);
});
```

Basically, I have this routes:

```
GET|HEAD     operation_calls            index
POST         operation_calls            store
GET|HEAD     operation_calls/create     create
PUT          operation_calls/{id}       update
```

Here's the way I make the post method, in my `blade.php` I have this form:

```
<div class="crud-operation-calls">
   <form role="form" method="POST" v-on:submit.prevent="storeOperations()">
    @csrf
     ...
   </form>
</div>
```

Also, I made a axios post only like this:

```
    axios.post('', {
          param1 : param1,
          param2 : param1
    })
    .then(response =>{

    })
```

And this is what I get:

```
Request URL: http://my-domain/operation_calls/create
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. It's like is passing the prefix of the current page. But I think axios just should go to the route I write in it's parameter. **Why is it changing?**

**What I tried:**

Clearing route cache of laravel: `php artisan route:cache`
Clearing cache of the browser
My `.env` file it's fine `APP_URL=http://my-domain/` because it works with other urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply prefix your route with a `/` like this

```js
 axios.post('/operation_calls', {
                  param1 : param1,
                  param2 : param1
            })
            .then(response =>{

            })
```

Comment: It works thanks, I didn't notice to try that I've always just routed without `/` and it worked fine. Now I'm afraid and I guess I have to use `/` always :/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are directly posting from http://my-domain/operation_calls/create. So it assumes as relative URL appends extra URI there. Try

```
  axios.post('{{ route('operation_calls.store') }}', {
              param1 : param1,
              param2 : param1
        })
        .then(response =>{

        })
```

Also, remove that `<form>` because we are posting via VUE, no need of extra FORM for posting. Use can change to `<form> to <div>.` Don't forget to pass CSRF token too in Vue post()

Comment: Thanks for your answer but `{{ route() }}` didn't work in a external javascript file it is taken as a string. And thanks for your advice, I'm new with Vue